# Turn a fatal crash into a non-fatal crashlytics report

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crash, fatal-error

The code in question:

```
final GenericAsyncTask task = new GenericAsyncTask();

        task.background = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(GCMIntentService.this.host);
                String addremove = "add";
                if(register == false) addremove = "remove";

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd", addremove));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subscription_key", SUBSCRIPTION_KEY)); // unique per app
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", str));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("os_family", "android"));
                    if(addremove.equals("remove")) nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hard", "" + hard));
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);
                    Log.i(LCHApplication.TAG, "Name Value Pairs: " + nameValuePairs.toString());

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    task.result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        task.callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i(LCHApplication.TAG, "registration response: " + task.result.toString());
            }
        };

        task.execute();
```

Which works great MOST of the time. Sometimes, however, `task.result.toString();` is sometimes `NULL` which throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I want to keep this crash because I want it to report in crashlytics so I can see how many people it's effecting. If I use a try/catch what can I throw to make sure it's a non-fatal crash instead? That way it will still report to crashlytics but it won't kill the app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to throw any caught exception, you can log them very easily like this:

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
  // handle your exception here! 
}
```

Source: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions